# Eclipse IvyDE Dependency Variable

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, ivy

I would like to define an ivy dependency using an ant variable. Right now I have this:

```
<dependency org="my.org.name" name="jar_name" rev="${release_version}"/>
```

In my ivysettings file I have:

```
<property name="release_version" value="${ANT_RELEASE_VERSION}"/>
```

One of the first tasks executed by my ant script is this:

```
<target name="getVersion">
    <echo message="Getting current version number" />
    <java classname="my.org.Version" >
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${SOME_PATH}/lib/some-jar.jar"/>
        </classpath>
        <redirector outputproperty="ANT_RELEASE_VERSION" />
    </java>
    <echo message="Version: ${ANT_RELEASE_VERSION}" />
</target>
```

Now this **WORKS** in runtime. When I execute my tasks, everything goes as expected and I get the correct version number. The issue is, eclipse is unable to compile the classpath due to the following error:

```
${ANT_RELEASE_VERSION}: not found
```

I tried solving this issue by defining an eclipse String substitution variable under:

```
Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> String Substitution
```

I set:

```
ANT_RELEASE_VERSION = 4.4.9
```

Yet eclipse is still not able to resolve my dependency, which results in my project never being able to compile (in eclipse). Is what I'm trying to do possible? Is there a way to get eclipse to compile without hardcoding the version number in my ant script/ivy settings file?

Comment: Have you looked at the ivy buildnumber task? It increments based on the files already published to your repository, very useful: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/buildnumber.html

Comment: @MarkO'Connor I did see this but we just started using a nexus repo, and unfortunately we do not have older version numbers published. Nor do I want to go through and publish X versions just to get this to work.

Comment: You can set the "defaultBuildNumber" attribute to start you at any point. If you're using Nexus I high recommend using this task.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an Eclipse property via :

```
Window > Preferences > Ant > Runtime > [Tab] Properties
```

and create a property named ANT_RELEASE_VERSION
to make it work with
ant scripts started within Eclipse.

Comment: I tried this, it does not work. I think it's because it needs to be evaluated in ivy, not ant.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a properties file inside your Eclipse project and refer it from projects Ivy settings.

Create a new .properties file in your project.

[image]

Put your properties in this file. In your case, you could create the property 'release_version' and assign to it the desired version number.

[image]

[image]

After that open the Ivy Classpath Container properties dialog by selecting 'Properties' from its right-button menu.

[image]

Next, open 'Settings' tab. Check 'Enable project specific settings' checkbox. In 'Property files' list add the properties file.

[image]

Press 'Ok'.